# Object-Relational Database Design Overlapping Subtypes with Nested Table

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, object-relational-model

I got a supertype Person and two (or more) subtypes Group1 and Group2.

A Person can be both Group1 and Group2, i.e., subtypes can overlap.

The supertype contains a nested table 'membership'.

When I create the subtype tables, seems like I have to repeat the NESTED TABLE statements again, otherwise I'll get the error message:

SQL Error: ORA-22913: must specify table name for nested table column or attribute

I got two questions:

- Is the way that I nested the same table 'membership' under the two subtype tables group1_table and group2_table correct?
- When I populate the data in the subtype tables, is it possible to 'refer' to the supertype table without duplicating the common values in the subtype tables?

[image: Supertype subtype ERD[er]

```
CREATE TYPE membership_type AS OBJECT
(membership_number INT,
 membership_name VARCHAR2(20),
 membership_date DATE)

CREATE TYPE membership_table AS TABLE OF membership_type

CREATE TYPE person_type AS OBJECT
(name VARCHAR2(100),
 membership membership_table) NOT FINAL

CREATE TABLE person_table OF person_type
OBJECT ID SYSTEM GENERATED
NESTED TABLE membership
STORE AS person_membership

CREATE TYPE group1_type under person_type
(extraAttribute1 VARCHAR2(10))

CREATE TABLE group1_table OF group1_type
NESTED TABLE membership
STORE AS group1_membership --Is the way that I nested the membership table correct?

CREATE TYPE group2_type UNDER person_type
(extraAttribute2 VARCHAR2(50))


CREATE TABLE group2_table OF group2_type 
NESTED TABLE membership
STORE AS group2_membership --Is the way that I nested the membership table correct?

INSERT INTO person_table VALUES
('person name',
membership_table(membership_type('123', 'membership name', '01-Aug-2016')));

INSERT INTO group1_table VALUES...
--can I refer to the supertype instead of duplicating the common value here?
```

Comment: Are you sure your group types should be subtype or person, rather than membership? Not sure I really understand your data model, or what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: Hi Alex. Yes, group types are under person not membership, i.e., there are two groups of person and a person can be both group1 person and group2 person.